# How can I remove the registered trademark symbol using ruby?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I am trying to remove the registered trademark symbol from the output of an Xpath query but my code fails to remove the symbol. From tutorials on-line I believe it can be done using rubys built in functions?

This is my inputted page:

http://h10010.www1.hp.com/wwpc/ie/en/ho/WF06b/321957-321957-3329742-89318-89318-5186820-5231694.html?dnr=1

I have tried the following:

```
csv << clues.map{|clue| doc.at("//td[text()='#{clue}']/following-sibling::td").text.strip.gsub(/\u2122/, '')}
```

Can anyone spot where I am going wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Resolved this issue by forcing the encoding to remove all non UTF-8 chars

Comment: The `™` didn't disappear when I did `text.encode('UTF-8', :invalid => :replace, :undef => :replace)` ... How did you do it?

Comment: For now I'm just doing `text.gsub('™', '')`